# Proving $\left(\frac{1}{z}\frac{d}{dz}\right)(z^{-v}J_v(z))=-z^{-v-1}J_{v+1}(z)$

Tags: derivatives, proof-verification, bessel-functions

> Use the series definition $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k(z/2)^{2k+v}}{k!\Gamma (1+k+v)}$$ to show that $$\left(\frac{1}{z}\frac{d}{dz}\right)(z^{-v}J_v(z))=-z^{-v-1}J_{v+1}(z)$$

I have shown that 
$$\left(\frac{1}{z}\frac{d}{dz}\right)(z^{-v}J_v(z))=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(k-1)!\Gamma (1+k+v)} \frac{z^{2k-2}}{2^{2k+v-1}}$$
But when I calculated the RHS, 
$$-z^{-v-1}J_{v+1}(z)=-z^{-v-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!\Gamma (2+k+v)} \frac{z^{2k+v+1}}{2^{2k+v+1}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k!\Gamma (2+k+v)} \frac{z^{2k}}{2^{2k+v+1}}$$ this does not seem to equal the LHS. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that in your LHS-result the sum actually starts at $k=1$, since under the derivative the $k=0$ term is constant and thus vanishes. After applying the derivative you have to shift $k \to k + 1$ in order to compare to RHS.

Comment: Yes, of course! Thank you for spotting this :)